# Need Help in a Project of C++

Tags: c++

**So this is the actual Problem**

Can anyone tell me that how I read the repective Data from the file, and how would I able to store it in variables (without using array) also the code should be generic, That if the number of series will incresed or decresed.. Code will not be affected... I Just can't understand that how would I store sata in variables and how.. Please Help.. :(

**Problem**

> A file contains information of a batsman. Information is no of series
>   played by the batsman. No of matches played in each series & score in
>   each match by the batsman. You have to read the data (without using
>   any array) and find average score and maximum score in all matches of
>   a series. In the end find overall average score and max score in all
>   matches.

**Input:**

> Read data from file "cricket.txt". First line contains no of seasons/
>   series played by the player. Next pair of lines contains matches
>   played by the batsman followed in next line scores by batsman in
>   different matches of a season. See sample "cricket.txt"
>
> 5
>
> 6
>
> 93 75 41 40 90 19
>
> 5
>
> 45 86 30 60 29
>
> 3
>
> 47 90 33
>
> 4
>
> 22 2 92 5
>
> 5
>
> 88 67 96 91 90
>
> First 5 shows player has played 5 seasons/ series
>
> Next 6 show in first series player has played 6 matches
>
> Next line has scores of player in 6 matches
>
> Next 5 show in second series player has played 5 matches
>
> Next line has scores of player in 5 matches
>
> So on in second last line 5 shows player has played 5 matches in 5th
>   series
>
> Last line has scores of player in 5 matches of last series

Comment: You probably need an array instead of multiple integer variables.

Comment: Bad luck, C++ is no scripting language.

Comment: It looks like you want an array

Comment: I need to initialize Variables not an array.. :(

Comment: I agree with the others, you could use an array to store values for different variables. If you absolutely wanted a name associated with each value, then you could use a HashMap

Comment: @HassanSohail What's the difference?

Comment: Actually, I am going to creating a module in which there is a file.txt from which we can able to read data, so as far as the data will be available in file, new variables created by itself.. For example, if there are four lines in text file, four variables will be created... No arrays will be allowed...

Comment: @HassanSohail What's the difference between an array of size 4, and 4 variables?

Comment: There is no need to invent new names inside the loop, each iteration would get its own unique variable with the same name.

Comment: @molbdnilo you are right, but it is the condition of project that no arrays will be allowed to declare... :(

Comment: *but it is the condition of project that no arrays will be allowed to declare.* -- So instead of using your legs to walk, you're going to use your stomach.  Great.

Comment: @HassanSohail Make a linked list, then. Or process one line at a time so you don't need to store more than one line. Is this a university assignment? If so, what are you supposed to be learning from this assignment?

Comment: Or maybe you should state in your question what exactly you are trying to achieve. E.g. how are the data processed further? Are you allowed to use any containers of std? Or should you implement your own container? At the current state of the question, the answer seems to be: "It cant be done this way"

Comment: If this is the case then I suspect we have an XY problem and that you only need a fixed number of integers to solve the problem.

Comment: @immibis, Yes this is my university project.. Actually what I supposed to do is, I have to make a module in which:
A file contains information of a batsman. Information is no of series played by the batsman. No of matches played in each series & score in each match by the batsman. You have to read the data (without using any array) and find average score and maximum score in all matches of a series. In the end find overall average score and max score in all matches.

Comment: @HassanSohail If you declare a variable called "a" inside the loop, every iteration gets a unique variable called "a". There is no need for either an array or inventing names. To compute an average you only need the sum and the number of elements.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for an array.

```
int a[10];

// Loop that assigns all elements in array a to 0
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    a[i] = 0;
}

// Array b will have all of it's members initialized to 0
int b[10]{};

// You can also assign different values to different elements of the array
b[0] = 6;
b[8] = 2;

// You can then use the array elements in operations
int c = b[0] * b[8];
```

If you want array like structure without compile time defined size, then use std::vector.

```
// An empty vector of ints
std::vector<int> d;

// A simple int
int e = 5;

// Push 2 values to the end of the vector
d.push_back(2);
d.push_back(e);

// Use the members for operations
int f = d.at(0) * d.at(1);
```

Comment: Or just `int a[10]{};`

Comment: Actually i need an int type variable to b initialize, not an array.. :(

Comment: @HassanSohail An array is basically a list of variables. You can initialize them independently or to any value you want.

Comment: Actually, I am going to creating a module in which there is a file.txt from which we can able to read data, so as far as the data will be available in file, new variables created by itself.. For example, if there are four lines in text file, four variables will be created... No arrays will be allowed...

Comment: @HassanSohail I have also added an example of a vector to my answer. It accomplishes your goal in a very elegant way.

Comment: @HassanSohail then you need a dynamic array or preferably std::vector instead of individual integers (which can not be dynamically created/named - C++ is not a scripting language).

Comment: @tambre Thanks for the Feedback, But yet I have no Idea that what are vectors... :(

Comment: @HassanSohail And that's why I made an example for you. Shouldn't be hard to Google for more functionality, if this isn't enough.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've now described the problem you're trying to solve instead of just the problem with the solution you came up with:

You don't need to invent variable names or use arrays to compute averages and maximums.

Here's an example of how you can compute an average of the numbers a user inputs:

```
float sum = 0;
int elements = 0;
float input = 0;
while (cin >> input)
{
    sum += input;
    elements += 1;
}
std::cout << "Average: " << sum / elements << std::endl;
```

It's easy to expand this to also keep track of the maximum value so far.

To expand to the average and maximum of a number of series, add another loop "around" it.

Comment: I edited the question I asked... Please go through it... Thank you... :)

Comment: @HassanSohail I read it. This should be all the help you need to solve it.